# Is there anything related to locking/blocking DocuSign account access when using the DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

Team, We developed a tool with DocuSign API integration to download Documents from DocuSign accounts using OAuth. We tested with couple of Free trial DocuSign accounts and able to download Documents. But after giving our tool access to one of our Business user, his account is locked/blocked after documents downloaded successfully by tool. The user is not able to login to his DocuSign account and when he tried to reset the password he doesn’t appear to be getting a password reset email from DocuSign.

**Is there anything related to locking/blocking DocuSign account access when using the DocuSign API?**

Answer (score 0):

Your customer will need to contact the DocuSign [help center](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport) and open a new ticket

Comment: Thanks @IvanD, will ask our Customer to open a ticket. But just want to understand my original question: Is there anything related to locking/blocking DocuSign account access when using the DocuSign API?

Comment: Not in the sense your customer reported. The only way to know is to check his account.